# Need help creating game close to "Pong" (Pygame)

Tags: pygame

As you read from the description (or not), I need help creating a game close to Pong.

I am really new in programming, and I am learning all by myself. The game you help me create will be my first game ever.

My version of game, explained:

Picture (Can't post a picture here since I am new):
http://www.upload.ee/image/3307299/test.png (THIS LINK IS SAFE)

So, number 1 stands for walls (black ones) 
Number 2 marks the area, where time stops (game over)
3 is your time survived.
Number 4 is the ball that bounces (like they do in Pong).

Code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 480])
paddle = pygame.image.load("pulgake.png")
pygame.display.set_caption("PONG!")


back = pygame.image.load("taust.png")
screen.blit(back, (0, 0))
screen.blit(paddle, (600, 240))
pygame.display.flip()

xpaddle = 600
ypaddle = 240 

delay = 10
interval = 10
pygame.key.set_repeat(delay, interval)


while True:
    screen.blit(back, (0,0))
    screen.blit(paddle, (xpaddle, ypaddle))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if i.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ypaddle = ypaddle - 10
                if ypaddle < 10:
                    ypaddle = 10
            elif i.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                ypaddle = ypaddle + 10
                if ypaddle > 410:
                    ypaddle = 410
```

I would like to have a bouncing ball, but i don't have the knowledge to create it.
It doesn't have to be really difficult(maybe using pygame.draw.circle?) 
Actually it has to be simple, because sprites are maybe too much for me.
My idea was to change coordinates every time ball gets to specific coordinates.
I am not just asking somebody to make a game I like, it's for educational purposes.

I would love to see some comments with the code you provide.
As I told, i just started learning it. 
My english isn't best. Sorry about that.
Thanks in advance!
(I know that my post is a bit confusing and unspecific)

If needed, I will upload the background and paddle picture too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Ball class, that will have 2 methods:

> update() - that will move the ball according to speed_x and speed_y and
>   check if any collisions are detected
>
> draw() - that will blit the surface/ or draw a circle at ball position.

another thing you have to think about, is collisions.
You can find if a point is in a rectangle like this:

We have a rectangle with points : `p1`,`p2`,`p3`,`p4`, `p0` is our testing point.

`p0` is in the rectangle if `dist(p0,p1) + disp(p0,p2) + ... + disp(p0,p4) == WIDTH+HEIGHT`

you can try to figure out the equation for a circle. Hint: radius is what you need.

EDIT: The class example:

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = [0,0]
        self.velocity = [1,0]
    def move():
        self.pos[0] += self.velocity[0]
        self.pos[1] += self.velocity[1]
    def draw(screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE,self.pos,5)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the fact that you even bothered to help me.

I guess I got the collide part, but the creating a working class just doesn't come out.

Could you just do an example (or maybe even a part of program)
I know that I am asking to put your free time in it, but I think that i am missing some of the important basics..

Comment: Also, how to set the new direction for ball after collision?

Comment: @Taneeleon just reverse the velocity

Comment: Thank you so much. I totally misunderstood the process of creating class (defining __init__). I think I will carry on and finish the game(some near future I hope:D) reputation +=

Answer (score 0):

To extend on @Bartlomiej Lewandowski, To make the ball you need to

Every loop `ball.update()` will do:

```
    ball.x += ball.xvel
    ball.y += ball.yvel`
```

Then

- if you collide with left/right walls `ball.x *= -1`
- if you collide with top/bot walls `ball.y *= -1`

Using pygame.Rect will simplfy logic

```
# bounce on right side
ball.rect.right >= screen.rect.right:
    ball.yvel *= -1

# bounce top
ball.rect.top <= screen.rect.top:

# bot
ball.rect.bottom >= screen.rect.bot:

# etc...
```

edit: Bart added different names but it's the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! Just one and final thing - the integration with paddle. I mean, how you tell python to watch the movement and recognize collision? Also, the stopwatch showing "survived time" is a difficulty.

Comment: For collision: in `move` you can check for collisions. There's 7 `Rect` collision functions for different situations. http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html -- If you use the `Sprite` class, there are several more collision functions: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html